# How do I centralize a card in a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is html:

```html
 <div class="service">
   <img src="img/indoor.svg">
   <p class="services">indoor</p>
   <button class="button">подробнее</button>
 </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="col-xxl-4">
   <div class="service">
     <img src="img/indoor.svg">
     <p class="services">BTL</p>
     <button class="button">подробнее</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="col-xxl-4">
   <div class="service">
     <img src="img/indoor.svg">
     <p class="services">на ТВ</p>
     <button class="button">подробнее</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 </div>
```

All my cards are shifted to the left. How can I center them? Offer any options. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have formatted the code and there are some stray <div> closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at the [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) and how it works. If you're indeed using Bootstrap 4 the col-xxl-* won't work, this only exists in Bootstrap 5. Bootstrap 4 only goes up to col-xl.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the cards then include this class `justify-content-center` in the `row` div. Example is in the following:

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            
            <div class="col-xxl-4">
            
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="" class="">
                    <p class="services">на ТВ</p>
                    <button class="button">подробнее</button>
                </div>            
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xxl-4">            
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="" class="">
                    <p class="services">на ТВ</p>
                    <button class="button">подробнее</button>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```